# Interfacing Microsoft .NET ( C# / F# ) with SWI-Prolog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I have problem with connecting Prolog to C#.

Visual Studio gives this following error :

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in SwiPlCs.dll"

and I really don't know how to handle this.

I think it came from the path I gave in the code :

```
using System;
using SbsSW.SwiPlCs;

namespace ptest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(@"C:\Program Files\swipl", @"C:\Program Files\swipl\boot64.prc");  // or boot64.prc
            var curPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("C:\\Program Files\\swipl\\bin");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(@"C:\Program Files\swipl\bin", @"C:\Program Files\swipl\boot;C:\Program Files\swipl;" + curPath);

            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {

                String[] param = { "-q" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(martin, inka))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, gloria))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, melanie))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, ayala))");
                using (var q = new PlQuery("father(P, C), atomic_list_concat([P,' is_father_of ',C], L)"))
                {
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["L"].ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("all children from uwe:");
                    q.Variables["P"].Unify("uwe");
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["C"].ToString());
                }
                PlEngine.PlCleanup();
                Console.WriteLine("finshed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Of interest: [Swi-cs-pl - A CSharp class library to connect .NET languages with SWI-Prolog](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you ask a question it helps to give more information rather than less.

Comment: Note: The last version of [SwiPlCs_1.1.60605.0.zip](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/download/index.htm) released on `2014.04.29 13:00` is a beta.

Comment: Of interest: `GitHub` [SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs) - source code for `Swi-cs-pl`

Comment: Of interest: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx)

Comment: The very short answer is that you need to add to the system [PATH](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) the directory containing `swipl.exe` which for me is `C:\Program Files\swipl\bin`. I am on `Windows 10` with `Visual Studio Community 2017` but as I noted on my system this is causing a `BadImageFormatException` Also I am using the source code from the interface page, not the code given in your question.

Comment: I downloaded the source from GitHub which I did not know includes the `HelloWorldDemo` example you are trying to run. Setting HelloWorldDemo as the startup project I was able to build the project, but in running it ran into a `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` when the code called `Marshal.WriteIntPtr`. Having experience with WriteIntPtr, this would probably require a full understanding of the data structures, pointers and setup/teardown. At this point I am stopping on writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a problem with latest versions of SWI_Prolog. Try installing older version of [SWI-Prolog 6.6.1 for Microsoft Windows (32 bit)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable/bin/w32pl661.exe) in C:/Program Files (x86) and use [SwiPlCs_1.1.60301.0.zip](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/SwiPlCs_1.1.60301.0.zip). Add reference to  SwiPlCs.dll in Visual Studio. It will work IA :)